# MySQLI string Won't update Info

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't find out why when I click my submit button it doesn't process the data. I currently have a query as such.

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass", "webdb");
 $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['page']);
 $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, (string) $_POST['content']);
 $query = "UPDATE `pages` SET `content`='$content' WHERE `name`='$page'";
 mysqli_query($link, $query);
 mysqli_close($link);
 header("location: index.php");
 ?>
```

To connect to this query I have my form that submits the data.

```
<form action="update_content.php" method="post">
<textarea name="content" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="Index" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Everything looks to be correct from where I stand. I've been racking my brain and looking all over the web for hours now and I cannot find a solution here.

Comment: To debug, try `echo $query;` to find out if it has some valid data in it before you fire the `mysqli_query`.

Comment: what error you getting now..?

Comment: Does your PHP query hide inside an `if` loop which checks for the Form submit?

Comment: So I found the issue. It's pathetic that I've been working on this for hours. Inside the $link variable my webdb wasn't set as a variable, but rather was attempting to connect to a non existent database. I apologize for wasting everyone's time I would have noticed it much sooner if I didn't have the query automatically redirect back to the old page. You having me echo the query caused me to spot the connection error however, so for that I thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

Print the query variable, so that you can know the query is constructed well.

(Comment the redirection so that you can see the query output)

**Step 2:**

If the values passed in the query aren't correct or empty, fix this by printing the
passed params (you can print `$_REQUEST` - Which will show all the values posted)

**Step 3**

if all these are correct and if the query is not executed correctly, then check your
database connection.

You can print out the connection variable `$link` to see if a connection is made successfully.

These these steps will help you sort out the issue.

Let me know if these steps doesn't help you.

Comment: The problem was actually solved when the connection issue was fixed. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer was when the redirect was disabled I was able to see that the connection was failing which was something I wasn't able to see until the redirect was disabled in order to see the echo $query string. Lesson Learned: Check to ensure all variables are correct. :)